# Applying lambda function on two columns in a Dataframe to get Geolocation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lambda

DataSet:

[image]

I am trying to get the pickup location using coordinates Pickup_longitude and Pickup and latitude. If I call the function separately it works. If I call in pandas along with lambda it doesn't work.

```
import requests
def fxy(x, y):
    url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+x+","+y+"&sensor=true"
    print(url)
    result=requests.get(url).json()
    str=result['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name']
    print(str)
    return str

#str1=fxy('40.69238281','-73.94309998')
#str1

locations=pd.read_csv("Data/locations.csv",sep=",")
locations['pickup_location'] = locations.apply(lambda x: fxy(str(x['Pickup_longitude']), str(x['Pickup_latitude'])))
```

Error:

> ---> 5     url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+x,y+"&sensor=true"
>         6     print(url)
>         7     result=requests.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+x+","+y+"&sensor=true").json()
>
> TypeError: ("ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature
>   matching types dtype('

Comment: Hello, try axis=1 inside apply (seems like you need to check row-wise)

Comment: I added this line . got the error like ---> 5     url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+x,y+"&sensor=true"
      6     print(url)
      7     result=requests.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+x+","+y+"&sensor=true").json()

TypeError: ("ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U56') dtype('<U56') dtype('<U56')", 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted the data frame columns to String and it worked.

locations['pickup_location'] = locations.apply(lambda x: fxy(str(x['Pickup_latitude']),str(x['Pickup_longitude'])),axis=1)